# Longitudinal, repeated measures, multivariate meta analysis

Tags: multivariate-analysis, panel-data, meta-analysis

I am trying to carry out a meta analysis with proportions in which I calculate the % of patients
with response and/or remission (measured with the same scale) to a treatment at determinated time points (week 8, week 16, month 6 and month 12). That is, I have two correlated outcomes measured at each time point.

By using the rma.mv function of metafor package, I have problems to decide what should be included in the random term. Please, could you say me if this is correct?:

rma.mv(yi, V, random = list( ~ outcome | trial, ~ time | trial), struct="UN", data=dat)

Many thanks

Comment: Questions about how to use software are often closed here as off-topic so you might consider asking on the mailing list dedicated to meta-analysis in R https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-sig-meta-analysis//